# unconditionally convert all unsigned char * to char * when calling a function

Tags: c++

I inherit some code that has many variables of type "unsigned char *", However, when I have to call some common functions like `strstr`, I have to do the conversion, like `strstr((char*)x, "....")`.

Wonder if there a compiler directive to convert variables automatically from `unsigned char *` to `char *` when calling a function.   I checked the code, it would have served the purpose.

If I don't the conversion manually, for example,  the following little code snippet will generate compiler error

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned char *str = "hello world";
    if (strstr(str, "wor")) {
        printf("yes\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler error  (command line: `g++ -std=c++11 te2a.cc`)

```
te2a.cc:17:15: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘uchar* {aka unsigned char*}’ [-fpermissive]
te2a.cc:18:23: error: call of overloaded ‘strstr(uchar*&, const char [4])’ is ambiguous
te2a.cc:18:23: note: candidates are:
In file included from te2a.cc:1:0:
/usr/include/string.h:321:14: note: char* strstr(char*, const char*) <near match>
/usr/include/string.h:321:14: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘uchar* {aka unsigned char*}’ to ‘char*’
/usr/include/string.h:323:22: note: const char* strstr(const char*, const char*) <near match>
/usr/include/string.h:323:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘uchar* {aka unsigned char*}’ to ‘const char*’
```

Comment: My suggestion is that you actually try to *fix* the problems, instead of just silencing them.

Answer (score 0):

The program behaviour on using such a cast is undefined. This is because the pointer types are unrelated.

In more detail: `char` can be signed or unsigned, the standard allows the implementation to choose. So what might be essentially a 'no-op' cast on one system is certainly not a 'no-op' cast on another one.

Also, a signed `char` pre-C++14 can be either 1's complement (-127 to +127) or 2's complement (-128 to 127). That does not make a conversion of a pointer of such a type particularly trivial.

One remedy would be to refactor your code to a `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks for the background info on signed vs unsigned char. There are too many occurrences of `unsigned char *` in the code.  Wish there is an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned char*` logically is not string, even if it's null terminated. The compiler warns you because it should not make the logical decision.

If you know it is indeed a compatible string, you may explicitly cast it:

```
if (strstr((const char*)str, "wor")
```

It's not elegant, and you should think again why you have the string being `unsigned char*`. Most people use `unsigned char*` just to distinguish itself from usual string, e.g. as buffers.

Comment: Thanks @calvin.  There are too  many such occurrences and it's real hard replace them all.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could write your own overload of strstr

```
strstr(unsigned char* s)
{
  strstr(reinterpret_cast<char*>(s));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the idea. Thought of this, but there are many such C functions (they all take `char *` instead of `unsigned char *`).

Comment: It doesn't take more than one or two days to overload all possible C string functions, and it's no brainer jobs. This should be quickest work-around.

Comment: Although ostensibly elegant, the behaviour will be undefined.

Comment: I had a look on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast and believe the behaviour is well defined